# ASP.NET/C# Download file protected by Google Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, cross-domain, google-authentication

I am trying to download a file that is hosted on an external website that is protected using Google Authentication. I would like the user of my application to login to their Google Account, and then have the application download the file from the other website.

From what I understand, the Google API will allow me to log a user into MY website and let them use their Google account as an account on MY website, but not allow them to log in on MY website and access Google Auth protected content from a DIFFERENT website.

So I guess my question boils down to: Am I right in my assumption? Or is it indeed possible to access another website's Google Protected content using a login system from my own website?

Any help is greatly appreciated.